# Business Being Sued - Should I Leave?

Tags: quitting, legal

I have a part-time job at a small publishing company where I basically upload articles that they have written for some of their paid subscription websites (user pays for a subscription to read the articles). Recently they have been asking me to copy and paste articles from popular news sites and upload them onto their paid subscription websites without even acknowledging the original site or writer.

The other day I saw an email on the business owners computer, regarding legal advice for a copyright infringement case involving the business.

So now I'm worried that they are getting sued, and I'm the one who has been actually uploading these articles that I might get into some serious legal trouble. For someone in college the last thing I want to be involved in is a lengthy legal case.

So I'm wondering should I just leave and find another job, or stay and see what happens? I have only been there for two months.

Thanks

Comment: Advice on what to do is considered off-topic, as are questions about legal matters. However, quitting and leaving likely won't protect you. You can still be named in a lawsuit, or subpoenaed to testify. One way to help your situation would be to put in writing (such as an email, and keep a copy safe somewhere) your protest of being asked to upload copyrighted content, then resign on those grounds. At least then there would be a record of your not complying with the orders. But this is not a bullet proof protection.

Comment: I would suggest going our legal site and ask if you are in trouble. Ofc if you find the work unethical you can always quit if you don't need the Job or can find a new one.

Comment: Related question: [My boss's behaviour seems unethical and possibly illegal. What should I do?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33605/my-bosss-behaviour-seems-unethical-and-possibly-illegal-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I will ask legal site if there are any implications for myself. Will probably leave anyway due to the ethical implications of stealing content.

Comment: [Here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/business-being-sued-for-copyright-infringement) is the question that was posted over on Law.SE.

Comment: @Craig: Remember the correct order: Find new job, sign contract, give notice. And don't tell anyone you are leaving before you give notice. As far as being sued is concerned, nobody wants to put you into jail. Someone might want money, and they will go after someone with money. Like the company, or your boss. So it's a bad situation, but not a disaster.

Comment: @Craig: And note that for everything you might have done so far, you can claim that you trusted your employer to have permission. But from now on you can't claim that anymore, so most definitely don't upload anything else!

Answer (score 6):

> Recently they have been asking me to copy and paste articles from
>   popular news sites and upload them onto their paid subscription
>   websites without even acknowledging the original site or writer.

Have you actually done any of that yet? If so, it might be too late. Consult a lawyer if you have because you could very well be fully liable for that and even face criminal charges (IANAL obviously).

If you haven't done any of that yet, you should refuse and find a new job ASAP.

**I cannot stress enough that under no circumstances should you engage in illegal copyright infringement now or in the future, not even on a direct order of your employer. If you are doing it currently, cease it immediately and consult a lawyer now.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a problem because I have been reposting these articles for maybe a month now. I originally thought that they had permission to do so, but recently I asked another employee and he said they didn't (which explains the lawsuit). Turns out this is more serious than I originally thought...

Comment: @Craig it definitely is, you need to get a lawyer _yesterday_. This could be super bad for you, like "you are personally liable for this criminally and civilly"-bad, and only a lawyer can help you mitigate that.

Comment: `I originally thought that they had permission to do so` Don't forget telling the lawyer this, it helps.

Comment: @deviantfan even if it's a lie.